# What this do in PHP?

Tags: php, function

I am working on a PHP project recently and found this piece of code:

```
public function createOrders($orders) {
  $args = new CreateOrders($orders);
  $result = $this->__soapCall("createOrders", array($args));
  return $result->rval;
}
```

I don't understand what this part is doing.

```
 $result = $this->__soapCall("createOrders", array($args));
```

Is it a recursive function?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php

Comment: Thank you, but I have read that document before and still don't understand. Can you be more precise? Is it recursive or not? Thank you.

Comment: Please specify, where exactly you have method `createOrders`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recursive, the line:

```
$result = $this->__soapCall("createOrders", array($args));
```

Executes a SOAP call to the `createOrders` method of the Web Service, so it receives a XML and parses it to a PHP asociated array that will be saved on `$result`. Usually this method is called when theres no WSDL.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php for more information.